# PHP/HTML - Refresh the web with combobox

Tags: php, html, combobox

How to do a combobox, which shows me the data under itself. Now I've got combobox which redirect me to other site. But I want to display the data without refreshing site under the combobox.

Comment: **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.**

Answer (score 0):

Use js to detect an OnChange of the combobox, with an ajax call to get the data from the server

Answer (score 0):

You must read about this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And as example:

```
<select id="dropdown-district">
  <option value="0" selected>choose distrinct...</option>
  <option value="1">Dist1</option>
  <option value="2">Dist2</option>
</select>
<script>
$( "#dropdown-district" ).change(function() {
           var office_value = $( "#dropdown-district" ).val();
           if (office_value != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "your_handler.php",  
                  data:{lang: lng, page_id: page_id}
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    $( ".regcenter-results" ).html(msg);
                });
            }
        }).trigger( "change" );
</script>
```

your_handler.php - returns some results when you change html combobox.